# Manage different instance separately with Terraform from Gitlab CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I have created a terraform module that create different aws ressources when applied.
The resources are :

1. An ec2
2. A security group
3. An Elastic IP

I would love to automate resource deployment via Gitlab Pipeline as it support Terraform.
However I have a question concerning my case.

This module has been created in the goal of creating an instance on demand for a specific person. So I would like to be able to have individual control over each resources for each person as opposed to a global "inventory" handled by Terraform state.

I was thinking about creating a branch for each person so I can destroy this person's resources if they are not needed anymore without doing it by hand on AWS console.

Let's say I run this module for personA and personB. If personA doesn't need these resources anymore it would be nice to be able to destroy it with terraform without impacting personB's resources.

Is my way to do it correct or is there a better one ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a general purpose module, then I would create a TF stack for each person. This way each instance would have independent state, and each user could manage their own instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So should I have a separated branch for each stack ?
So gitlab could manage differents TF states by branches

Comment: Same branch, just two separate TF implementations, each in it's own folder.

Comment: Sorry for being late to respond but only checking this during work hours.
So I'll create a new folder for each person who need an instance and just copy the files from the terraform module modifying the values needed. And I'll store the state as a file in the repo and not as a state managed by gitlab ?